# How can I use the second column in this primary key both in ORDER BY clause as well as update it using an UPDATE command

Tags: cassandra

Below is the table.

```
CREATE TABLE threadpool(
threadtype int, 
threadid bigint, 
jobcount bigint, 
valid boolean, 
PRIMARY KEY (threadtype, jobcount, threadid)
);
```

I want to run the below 2 queries on this table.

1. `SELECT * FROM threadpool WHERE threadtype = 1 ORDER BY jobcount ASC LIMIT 1;`
2. `UPDATE threadpool SET valid = false WHERE threadtype = 1 and threadid = 4;`

The second query fails with the below reason.

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="PRIMARY KEY column "threadid" cannot be restricted (preceding column "jobcount" is either not restricted or by a non-EQ relation)"
```

Can any body please help me in modelling the data to support both the above queries.

Comment: If you plan to use jobcount as a counter and want to have Cassandra present you all threads with the highest counter value, you probably won't have much success with your data model. Can you move the jobcounter out of the PK, add another threadpool_id instead and do the sorting manually in your application?

Comment: @StefanPodkowinski Thanks for your suggestion. My intention is to always get the threadid with the least jobcount. hence, I limit the select query to return only 1 value. In a way I want cassandra to sort the values for me. But once I get the threadid with least job count i will be assigning it a new job. Hence, I also would want to increment the jobcount value for that threadid by 1 (Update statement to set jobcount = jobcount + 1).  Can you let me know if this is possible with the above datamodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your described data model can't work, as

- only values of datatype `counter` can be incremented using a CQL statement
- counter tables can only have the counter as a single column beside the PK
- you cannot sort by counter values